# How can I expose my Rest services in multiple swagger pages.

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger

I am using Spring boot to create some Rest services. How can I expose my Rest services in multiple swagger pages. 
For example All delete methods be in a separated page!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `springdoc-openapi` you can create multiple `@RestController` classes and separate them into Groups as scribed [here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/213).

As described int to the link above you have to enable the entry `springdoc.api-docs.groups.enabled=true`

And create a Group in your config

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi storeOpenApi() {
    String paths[] = {"/store/**"};
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().setGroup("stores").pathsToMatch(paths)
            .build();
}
```

The store open-api json will be available on
`http://host:port/v3/api-docs/store`

Answer (score 0):

You may use tags to alter the grouping like explained here : [Grouping Operations With Tags](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/).

Here is an example annotation you could have on your controller methods :

```
@ApiOperation(tags = { "delete" }, value = "this API operation will be grouped under the delete section", nickname = "myMethod")
```

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, but I like to have different endpoints, then I can expose different access types to different swagger users.